# Error while adding custom object to JObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

These are my classes:

```
public class RequestEntity
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
    public List<Parameters> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsRecent { get; set; }
}
```

After setting value to:

```
List<RequestEntity> request = new List<RequestEntity>();
```

Now I need to create a `JObject` with 2 properties.

```
JObject requestObject = new JObject();
JProperty property1 = new JProperty("Details", request);
JProperty property2 = new JProperty("SpanInDays", 10);
requestObject.Add(property1);
requestObject.Add(property2);
```

The line `JProperty property1 = new JProperty("Details", request);` is giving me following error.

`Could not determine JSON object type for type DAL.Entity.RequestEntity.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use some kind of `JToken` as the value of a `JProperty` (at least in the case of complex types). You can easily get one of those by using `FromObject`:

```
JProperty property1 = new JProperty("Details", JToken.FromObject(request));
```